# JUnit 5 fails to run a methodSourced test

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have the following JUnit 5 test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@DisplayName("Test Valid Video With Slides")
@MethodSource("slidesTestsArguments")
void testValidVideoWithSlides(VersionData versionData) {

    SlidesResponse slidesResponse = testsHelper.callVideosSlidesRequest(versionData);
    assertAll(
        "Validating response of transcript ep for a video with transcript",
        () -> assertEquals(validPublishedSlidesVideoId, slidesResponse.videoId, "VideoId is not as expected"),
        () -> assertNotEquals(0, slidesResponse.slides.size(), "Segments number should be more than 0")
    );
}
```

and a supplier method in the same class:

```
static Stream<Arguments> slidesTestsArguments() {

    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(new V2Data()),
        Arguments.of(new V3Data()),
        Arguments.of(new V4Data())
    );
}
```

For some reason I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker getExecutableInvoker()' of interface org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$1(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:299)
        at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$5(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
        ... 55 more
```

This is part of the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.aaaaaa</groupId>
<artifactId>aasasa-dfsdfsdfsd-api-test</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/SanityTMTestsSuite*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit5 engine and JUnit 5 API -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit4 engine and JUnit 4 API  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java 15.

I work on latest IntelliJ env.

The very same happened for me on the same class with :

```java
static Stream<Integer> testArguments() {
     return Stream.of(1, 2 ,3);
}


@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testArguments")
void testInteger(Integer n) {
     System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Done. Partially, it is very long :)

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character. Maybe that is the reason why your `@MethodSource`is not found

Comment: You are correct convention-wise ofcourse, but that unfortunately didn't help...

Comment: The main problem is *Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest*.

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve]

Comment: I understand that, and I think this is what I do. Do I do it correctly?

Comment: I think *static Stream<Arguments> slidesTestsArguments()* should be *static Stream<VersionData> slidesTestsArguments()*

Comment: @Jens Use of `Stream<Arguments>` should work.

Comment: I tested something similar to your code. Works fine. (I didn't use maven though). Only question left for me: can you show the inheritance relationship between `VersionData` and `V2Data`, `V3Data` and `V4Data`? This and a sample implementation of the method to test would miss for me to get a [mre].

Comment: @cyberbrain it is simply V2Data extends VersionData, both are simple POJOs

Comment: I made some post updates. Hope that helps

Comment: @cyberbrain (and @Gens), I added a minimal reproducible example (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml looks weird. You have too many test libraries as dependencies, and mix JUnit versions.
For start, try it with something smaller like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.aaaaaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>aasasa-dfsdfsdfsd-api-test</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.0</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, leaving only

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

under the surefire dependencies section fixed the problem.